# Mathematical meaning of the $\log n$ complexity of assignment of finding maximum algorithm

Tags: probability, algorithms, expectation, computational-complexity

There is an algorithmic analysis of maximum element finding algorithm in Dr. Knuth's vol 1 book. There he has analyzed the following pseudo code:

```
            int main() {
            // array[n] is initialized with same random values
            // n can be large
            // assume n = 9
            int array[n] = {2,3,-4,1,0,6,2,3,4}; 
            int j,m;

            //initialize
            j = n-1;                        //assign last index to j
            m = arr[n-1];                   //assign last value to m

            int k = n-2;                    //assign 2nd last index to k

            //loop

            while(k>=0) {               // stop the loop is k reaches the first element
                if(arr[k] <= m) {       // m is the current maximum value
                    k--;
                    continue;               // array[k] is less than current maximum
                                                        // So, we we need to go back and decrement k
                }else {                 // else block
                    j = k;                      // found new maximum index
                    m = arr[k];             // found new maximum value
                }
            }

            printf("%d %d\n",m,j);
            return 0;
        }


        // n can be large enough with n randomly initialized values.
```

The concerned question was

> how many times on average the else block executes ?

He has explained it using generating function and finally found the result to be

> $$H_n - 1$$

I convinced to myself using the following expected value method :

Let $E(n)$ be the expected no of times the `else` block executes.
Now;

- if 1st last element is not max then $E(n) = E(n-1)$.
- if 1st last element is max then $E(n) = E(n-1) + 1$.

  1st last element can be max with probability $\frac{1}{n}$ and probability that it can not be the max is $\frac{n-1}{n}$.

So,

$$\begin{align*}
E(n) &= \left [ E(n-1) +1 \right ]\left ( \frac{1}{n} \right ) + \left [ E(n-1) \right ]\left ( \frac{n-1}{n} \right ) \\
&= E(n-1) + \frac{1}{n} 
\end{align*}$$

Using recursion tree ; complexity of $ \ E(n) = O(H_n) \approx O(\log n)$ for large value of n.

Mathematically it is fine to have this answer as $\log n$, but what does it mean actually ?

If we simply take the increasing numbers, then `else` block will executes zero time and for decreasing sequence `else` block executes `n` times. So the average no of times else block will run seems to be $\frac{n}{2}$. Now we know this is wrong, why not all cases are equality likely ? I couldn't figure out the reason why is it logarithmic bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I really think it would be more appropriate to post this in [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com).

The question is, having any possible combination of random numbers in `arr`, what is the average number of times that the algorithm goes inside the `else` block.

There are some cases, where the algorithm does not go into `else` block at all (for example, when `arr` is sorted in decreasing order); There are also cases where the algorithm goes into `else` block $n-1$ times (for instance, when `arr` is sorted in increasing order); Similar to these extreme cases, there could be cases where the algorithm goes into that block $2, \cdots, n-2$ times. But the question is which ones are more likely to happen? The answer is found using combinatorics techniques. On average (given any possible combination of numbers), the algorithm goes into the `else` block $\log n$ times. Because the probability that the the algorithm visits `else` only few times, is much higher than the probability of going into that block a large number of times.

You need to note that the number of times that the algorithm *needs* to go into `else` block only 1 times is much more likely than $n-1$ times. Similarly with 2 and etc. As a very simple example, consider those extreme cases which we both discussed. The number of times that the algorithm does not go inside `else` block is $(n-1)!$ times, while the number of times that the algorithm goes inside `else` block $n-1$ times is just 1.

Comment: Yes they are not equally likely. Thanks. Should I move this qs to cs ?

Comment: @Debashish That's up to the moderators' decision. With the upvotes, I don't think you should move it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think the recursion relation doesn't hold.  Seems like n is the length of the array and you conditioned on whether the first element set to start is the max or not.  I tried this too but it doesn't work because when the first element is the max clearly, E(n)=0 but when it's not there's no general relation.  Consider the array 5,2,3,1,4. I think it just depends on how many elements are greater than the first one plus how they are arranged.

Comment: We are iterating from back, it is a top down recursive approach

Comment: I see.  Sorry for the mistake.